# How to get all possible generic type in StructureMap?

Tags: generics, class, structuremap

I just used StructureMap few days ago. I use StructureMap for collecting all validator class like the following code.

```
public class BaseClassA {}

public class ClassB : BaseClassA {}

public class ClassC : BaseClassB {}

public BaseClassAValidator : IValidator<BaseClassA>() {}
```

In StructureMap, I only register `IValidator<BaseClassA>` interface for `BaseClassAValidator` class. But I want to get the same result when I call `IValidator<ClassB>` or `IValidator<ClassC>` that mean StructureMap should return `IValidator<T>` where T is requested class or parent class of requested class.

Is it possible? Or I need to manually call it.

Answer (score 0):

From the answer to [How to use a convention for IRepository<T> with StructureMap mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536444/how-to-use-a-convention-for-irepositoryt-with-structuremap-mapping/6541249)

```
var c = new Container(x =>
{
    x.Scan(scan =>
    {
        // there are other options to expand which assemblies to scan for types
        scan.TheCallingAssembly(); 
        scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof (IValidator<>));
    });
});
```

Now if you request `IValidator<ClassC>`, you should get `BaseClassCValidator`.

Comment: It's my mistaken. I don't see that StackOverflow doesn't show my all question. I just update this question. Let's see it.