# How to use a convention for IRepository<T> with StructureMap mapping

Tags: structuremap

Is there a way in StructureMap to do this kind of repetitive mapping with one line or a convention?

```
    For<IRepository<Mailout>>().Use<MailoutRepository>();
    For<IRepository<MailServer>>().Use<MailServerRepository>();
    For<IRepository<MailoutStatus>>().Use<MailoutStatusRepository>();
    For<IRepository<MailoutTemplate>>().Use<MailoutTemplateRepository>();
    For<IRepository<Publication>>().Use<PublicationRepository>();
    For<IRepository<Recipient>>().Use<RecipientRepository>();
```

Comment: Related question - if I have a generic Repository<T>, is there an easy way to map that (e.g. <IRepository<>>().Use<Repository<>>() )?

Comment: For the related question, see [Open Generic Types in StructureMap](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2009/01/13/open-generic-types-in-structuremap/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To map `IRepository<Mailout>` to `MailoutRepository`, use:

```
var c = new Container(x =>
{
    x.Scan(scan =>
    {
        // there are other options to expand which assemblies to scan for types
        scan.TheCallingAssembly(); 
        scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof (IRepository<>));
    });
});
```

To map `IRepository<Mailout>` to `Repository<Mailout>`, use:

```
var c = new Container(x =>
{
    x.For(typeof (IRepository<>)).Use(typeof (Repository<>));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could greate something like Repository base :

```
public class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T> where T : Entity
```

then have something like this :

```
public class UserRepository : RepositoryBase<User>, IUserRepository
public class OtherRepository : RepositoryBase<Other>, IOtherRepository
```

where your repositories interfaces impelement the generic repository interface like that :

```
public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<User>
public interface IOtherRepository : IRepository<Other>
```

and then you could register it like that :

```
For(typeof (IRepository<>)).Use(typeof (RepositoryBase<>));
```

It works for me.

Comment: I think he's looking to instantiate `UserRepository`, not `RepositoryBase<User>`, which is what it seems your code does..?

Comment: In fact you can resolve the UserRepository without any problem doing just that ex: HomeController(IUserRepository userRepository)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround, as we couldn't find any shorter way of making that mapping.

First, map to an open generic implementation class, as [discussed elsewhere](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2009/01/13/open-generic-types-in-structuremap/):

```
For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(ConcreteRepository<>));
```

Then, for each repository with custom behavior, add extension methods on the appropriate interface.  For instance, supposing your `MailoutStatusRepository` has a method `GetStatus()`, you might translate that to an extension method on `IRepository<MailoutStatusRepository>`:

```
public static Status GetStatus(this IRepository<MailoutStatusRepository> repo,
                               Mailout mail)
{
    return mail.Status;  // or whatever
}
```

Now you have the custom repository behavior without having to worry about casting StructureMap's output to some custom class:

```
var repo = container.GetInstance<IRepository<MailoutStatusRepository>>();
var status = repo.GetStatus(mailout);
```

Another benefit of this approach is that your custom repository behavior works regardless of your repository implementation: in tests and in production code.  The only downside (I think) is that your repositories are necessarily stateless, but we haven't found this to be a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scan(x =>
{
    x.WithDefaultConventions();
    x.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(UserRepository));
    x.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(Repository<>));
    x.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IRepository<>));
});
```

WithDefaultConventions is the important part of the shown code, because with this setting you say StructureMap to use the convention of mappping IUserRepository  to UserRepository . So StructureMap proceed from the assumption that the class is named like the name of the interface without the prefix I.